# How to check and remove array value with specific data type?

Tags: php, arrays, types

I have array variable which is unpredicted format and length. For example:

```
$arrayData = array(
   0 => (int) 100,
   1 => (date) 2012-12-01,
   2 => array(
       0 => (string) 'some string',
       1 => (int) 200,
   ),
   3 =>  (string) 'another string'
);
```

I need to remove array key and it's value and keep just string data type.

Maybe some one can suggest me the right way to resolve that problem instead of use loop and gettype.

Result will be:

```
$arrayData = array(
   2 => array(
       0 => (string) 'some string',
   ),
   3 =>  (string) 'another string'
);
```

or:

```
$arrayData = array(
   0 => (string) 'some string',
   1 =>  (string) 'another string'
);
```

or others suggestion result are welcome.

Comment: Why dont you wanna use gettype. Do you wanna remove the array in yo key [2] or just remove the (string) 'some string'.?

Comment: I'm not positive, but this sounds like a problem recursion could solve

Comment: @ravz, just want to know if there are php build-in function or other pretty way.

Comment: yes array_walk_recursive is what you are looking for i guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the array and use the `gettype()` function to keep/remove array items. However, you need a recursive function to handle arrays within array. Notice the careful use of two `&` in the following code example:

```
$arrayData = array(
    0 => (int) 100,
    1 => '2012-12-01',
    2 => array(
        0 => (string) 'some string',
        1 => (int) 200
    ),
    3 => (string) 'another string'
);
function remove_nonstring_recursive(&$array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        $type = gettype($value);
        if ($type == "array") {
            remove_nonstring_recursive($value);
        } elseif ($type != "string") {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
}
remove_nonstring_recursive($arrayData);
var_dump($arrayData);
// array(3) {
//   [1]=>
//   string(10) "2012-12-01"
//   [2]=>
//   array(1) {
//     [0]=>
//     string(11) "some string"
//   }
//   [3]=>
//   string(14) "another string"
// }
```

Original answer - using `array_walk_recursive` with global variable

```
$arrayData = array(
    0 => (int) 100,
    1 => '2012-12-01',
    2 => array(
        0 => (string) 'some string',
        1 => (int) 200
    ),
    3 => (string) 'another string'
);
$arrayDataFiltered = array();
function remove_non_string($value, $key) {
    global $arrayDataFiltered;
    if (gettype($value) == "string") {
        $arrayDataFiltered[] = $value;
    }
}
array_walk_recursive($arrayData, "remove_non_string");
var_dump($arrayDataFiltered);
// array(3) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(10) "2012-12-01"
//   [1]=>
//   string(11) "some string"
//   [2]=>
//   string(14) "another string"
// }
```

Comment: your prev method was better as it was faster one without loops.

Answer (score 3):

You have [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) if you don want to use loops.

```
<?php
$arrayData = array(
   0 => (int) 100,
   1 => (date) 2012-12-01,
   2 => array(
       0 => (string) 'some string',
       1 => (int) 200,
   ),
   3 =>  (string) 'another string'
);

array_walk_recursive($arrayData, 'test_print');

function test_print($value, $key)
{
   //your code to remove
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't now how to do it without recursion, but with the help of array_walk_recursive you could get want:

```
<?php
    $arrayData = array(
        0 => 100,
        1 => 2012-12-01,
        2 => array(
            0 => 'some string',
            1 => 200,
        ),
        3 =>  'another string'
    );

    $objTmp = (object) array('flat' => array());
    array_walk_recursive($arrayData, create_function('&$v, $k, &$t', '$t->flat[] = gettype($v);'), $objTmp);

    var_dump($objTmp->Flat);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach main arrray and check each value for it is string or not.
In the end you will have an array of only strings.

```
foreach($arrayData as $key => $value){
    if(is_string($value)){
    $new[] = $value;
    }
}
```

`$new` will have only strings.